# in angular-ag-grid, how to add vertical line/separator on specific column headers only?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to add vertical separator only to Main Header columns - 'Main-H-Col2' and 'Main-H-Col3' and not on sub column headers. How to achieve this ?

```
export const TestAgGridColumns = [

  {headerName: 'Col1', field: 'col1', sortable: true, filter: true, lockVisible: true, lockPosition: 
                true, editable: false},
  {headerName: 'Main-H-Col2',
    children: [
      { headerName: 'sub-H-Col2',
        field: 'sub-H-Col2',
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
        lockVisible: true,
        lockPosition: true,
        cellRenderer: 'agCellRenderer',
        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: {
          values: ['Y', 'N'],
          cellRenderer: 'agCellRenderer',
        }
      }
    ]},
  {headerName: 'Main-H-Col3',
    children: [
      { headerName: 'sub-H-col3-1', field: 'sub-H-col3-1', sortable: true, filter: true, lockVisible: 
        true, lockPosition: true,
        cellRenderer: 'agCellRenderer',
        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
        cellEditorParams: {
          values: ['Y', 'N'],
          cellRenderer: 'agCellRenderer',
        }
      },
      { headerName: 'sub-H-col3-2', field: 'sub-H-col3-2', sortable: true, filter: true, lockVisible: 
        true, lockPosition: true},
      { headerName: 'sub-H-col3-2', field: 'sub-H-col3-2', sortable: true, filter: true,
        lockVisible: true, lockPosition: true, editable: false,
        tooltipField: 'sub-H-col3-1Changes',
        tooltipComponentParams: { color: '#ececec' }}
    ]}
```

];

Comment: Please could you create a plunker to recreate it?

Comment: You should be able to use cellStyle

Comment: Thanks. Adding cellStyle: { border-right: 1px solid #aaa } , i was able to add create a separator on specific columns.